# Sending a large parametrized data set as a GET request

Tags: javascript, http, get

What's the best way to send a large data set via a GET request.

- I cannot use POST because of some design limitations.
- I can use jQuery or any other library, sizzle is preferable.
- I have a complex data set that has nestings within it, and json fits the bill well.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "large"?

Comment: What are the design limitations which makes POST unusable? Its limit is **much** higher.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GET requests shouldn't exceed 1-4 kilobytes in size due to browser and server limitations. You would have to split your request in chunks to do this.

If the data comes from a form, you could, for example utilize jQuery's [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function to put the data into one string. Then split the string into kilobyte-sized chunks and send it out using Ajax. You would have to have a server-side script that glues the chunks back together, possibly using a unique identifier specified in the Ajax requests.

Some sources on the length limitation:

- MSDN: [Maximum  URL length is 2083 characters in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427)
- [Various server and browser tests](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html), from 2006 but should still give a half-way representative overview

Comment: [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.2.1) mentions 255 bytes as safe upper limit. It's however an old spec. Nowadays I think 2K is safe, but I am unsure about mobile clients. The limit by the way doesn't apply on query stirng part only, but on the entire URI.