# HTTP request is not hitting to server

Tags: java, html, tags

I'm working on a big scenario but the area which is impacted that belongs to textarea, where I'm giving a too big value and I have written the below code:

```
<div class="table-cell five-column">
                <il:fieldSet formObject="${lessorDetailsVO}">
                    <il:checkboxField name="displayNonNotification" label="Display Non-Notification Message"/>
                    <il:textArea name="displayNonNotificationMessage" label="" rows="4" cols="30"/>
                </il:fieldSet>
</div>
```

When I'm giving the request with small data then particular data is getting bind up with request and storing in to database, but when I'm trying to put the data with large amount then this field is not binding up with the same request and showing the 400 error for same request. Please find the image below which will help you to understand.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nuwlv.png)

Please let me know what can cause this issue, I know 400 error comes when there is problem in the request but here the problem is fields are not binding up with the request. Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: May be you are using GET which has limit. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request

Comment: I feel the same but framework is not allowing me to change it to POST.

Comment: Under inspect element I found framework is setting method= "post" but request is passing with GET. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GET then you will have to face size limitations. GET requests shouldn't exceed 1-4 kilobytes. If you cannot change to POST and have to use GET then you can break down your data into chunks of 1-4 kilobytes.

Please look at [sending large dataset as GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977070/sending-a-large-parametrized-data-set-as-a-get-request).

Hope it helps.